# using special character in string.format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

If I have following string builder:

```
var a = string.Format("{0}-{1}", model.FirstName, model.LastName);
```

and I want to use special character `&#8211` instead of `-`. I tried the following:

```
var a = string.Format("{0}\u8211{1}", model.FirstName, model.LastName);`
```

but it is giving me the `舑` symbol. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please ask a *question*. You've said what you want to do - so what happens when you try it? Note that your quote is in the wrong place at the moment. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: and your code has little mistake quote place`var a = string.Format("{0}-{1}", model.FirstName, model.LastName);`

Comment: Are you looking for this..string a = string.Format("{0}&#8211{1}", model.FirstName, model.LastName);

Comment: Or var a = string.Format("{0}\u8211{1}", model.FirstName, model.LastName);?

Comment: C# supports Unicode source files. Just copy the correct character and paste it into your code

Comment: @USER1765862 what output you expects. please specify

Comment: Why do so many people try to answer an unspecific LQ question before OP responds to even a single attempt to clarify?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer [hat is really a question for [MSO] but....] because we don't all see the same ambiguity in a question, and thus the need for clarification.

Comment: @Richard Fair enough. It's always surprising how many different interpretations of the same question there are (especially short unspecific ones).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I used var a = `string.Format("{0}\u8211{1}", ...)` but I'm getting `舑` symbol.

That's because you're using the decimal representation, where in C# [Unicode escape sequences are hexadecimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx).

You're looking for [`\u2013`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

But anyway there's no real reason to do this, because you can just insert the `–` character in your source string. C# supports Unicode code files.

Comment: I got it, thank you for clarifying situation(its for deleted answer)

Comment: Beat me to it [8211](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8211/index.htm) and [2013](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) for reference.

Comment: And this is why we don't jump to answer before we know the question ;)

Comment: @Manfred the sad thing is that this is their 500+th question, they should know better by now.

Comment: @CodeCaster The sad part is this is their 259th question in the C# tag and they still can't use google for something as simple as this.